# Using scrapy to query a database for PDFs then download them

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and python so please bear that in mind :)

I am doing a piece of research and I need to download a lot of publicly available PDF docs from a government website. The problem is that there are about 11,000 pages of search results, each with 10 PDFS.

What I would like to do is write a script using scrapy that:

1) Passes pre-defined search parameters to the document search engine on the site site (e.g. Keyword, Business Name, date from, date to etc)
2) Runs the search query and obtains the results
3) Automatically downloads the ALL the PDFs that are displayed as a result of the query (not just the first page of results) that match my defined parameters to my machine/uploads them to a google drive

Any pointers on something I can use? I've not found anything that does this - any help would be much appreciated, it's for a very good cause!

this is where I am so far:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class fos(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "XXX"


allowed_domains = ["XXX"]

start_urls = ["XXX"]


def parse(self, response):

    for href in response.css('div#all_results h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield Request(
                url=response.urljoin(href),
                callback=self.parse_article
            )

    def parse_article(self, response):
        for href in response.css('div.download_wrapper a[href$=".pdf"]::attr(href)').extract():
            yield Request(
                url=response.urljoin(href),
                callback=self.save_pdf
            )

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        self.logger.info('Saving PDF %s', path)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: You have python and scrapy. You have all you need. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the note Alec - you're right I seem to have everything I need but given I am so new to coding it's a bit tricky to navigate. I'll add the code I am using...

Comment: You don't need 'save_pdf', download images within 'parse_article'. Use 'BytesIO' for fetching and storing files.

Answer (score 0):

Other than python and scrapy, I would suggest using threading for this many pages.
Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and a good [tutorial](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: Thanks Ohad - appreciate the response, I will have a look into this!

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is a wonderful tool for such task, it saves time in going through different custom functions that you'd otherwise have to do and using it's pipeline, you can download files (pdfs) in parallel using your favorite libraries (i.e., multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool)

If you can share exact links, may be I can assist you directly.

Comment: Thanks Janib - a site similar to the one we are looking at is: Thanks Janib. A site similar to the one we are looking at is: https://www.fca.org.uk/publications/search-results?